# Creating DE or Audience based on email link clicks?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have a requirement. Whenever someone clicks a link in an email sent, an audience or a Data Extension needs to be created.Is this possible using Automation Studio? If not is there a specific AMPScript function which can be used? Would anyone be kind enough to elaborate on the above?

Thank you

Comment: You want to create a data extension for each subscriber that clicks on a link in any email... potentially millions of data extensions? Or do you want a new data extension for each distinct link in your emails and that contains all subscribers that clicked on the link? Or do you want a single data extension for each email send containing any subscribers that clicked a link in that email? Or do you want a single data extension to hold all clicks - basically the _Click data view?

Comment: I apologise for not being specific. My requirement would be that I want a single data extension for each email send containing any subscribers that clicked a link in that email.

Comment: It's feasible using SSJS to create your target data extensions and associated query activities and add those query activities using the API to an Automation. It's not a trivial piece of work, however, and getting the thing to scale would be a challenge. I'd probably want to take a step back from the narrow question and ask, "what are you trying to achieve here?". How would you be using these data extensions? Who would be using them?

Answer (score 1):

**Programmatic solution:**

Like Macca said, creating a process that would take care of everything on its own is possible but requires some SSJS coding. The high-level outline of such process in the Automation Studio could be:

1. Create an SQL query to query the _Job data view to find new email sends
2. Run SSJS script activity to create Data Extensions for newly found sends. Here's an example SSJS that I used for a similar use case:

```js
Platform.Load("core","1.1");  
//Set Data Extension properties
var fields = [
          { "Name" : "SendID", "FieldType" : "Number"},
          { "Name" : "SubscriberKey", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "EventDate", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
          { "Name" : "EventType", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "BatchID", "FieldType" : "Number"},
          { "Name" : "ClientID", "FieldType" : "Number"}
        ]
      
var NewClickDE = {
        "CustomerKey" : "Clicks",  //pass DE CK based of SQL query from previous step
        "Name" : "Clicks",  //pass DE name based of SQL query from previous step
        "Fields" : fields
     };
      
//Create Data Extensions   
var ClickDE = DataExtension.Add(NewClickDE);
```

3. Interact with SFMC's API to create a new [Query Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_query_activity.htm) and then to [Perform a Query Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api.htm).

If it doesn't need to be in real-time and you don't want to go into writing complex SSJS, you could definitely use Automation Studio to fulfil this requirement.

**Manual solution:**

As a prerequisite, you would have to create a new Data Extension and a new Automation for each email sent. In the automation, create an SQL query that will populate your Data Extension:

```
Select
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
j.DeliveredTime as SendTime,
c.EventDate as ClickTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey
from [_Job] j
join [_Click] c
on j.JobID = c.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
where
o.IsUnique = 1 and
j.EmailID = <EmailID>
```

Keep the Automation running for as long as you want to "monitor" the send job for new clicks - usually, around 1 week would be enough.

Documentation:

- [Data View: Click](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5)
- [SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

I agree fully with [@zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj) in using SSJS to automate this process. To add to her good solution design, I will help with some additional code to her point #3. Following code will create a query definition, and execute it once, from SSJS:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core", "1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
     
   var queryDef = {
    Name : queryName,
    CustomerKey : queryKey,
    TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
    TargetType : "DE",
    ObjectID: guid,

    Target:{
     Name: destinationDeName,
     CustomerKey: destinationDeKey
    },
       QueryText : "SELECT foo FROM bar"
   };

   var QDstatus = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);
   qd = QueryDefinition.Init(guid);
   var perform_status = qd.Perform(); 

</script>
```